# statement's auto generated Keys seem useless Java w/ MariaDB 10.x

Tags: sql-update, return, key, mariadb, generated

my research about auto_generated_keys gave me some hints about prepared statements might be bugged but no issues concerning ordinary statements as visible below.

The code so far does give me the keys in a resultset which has as many rows as the statement updated. But against my expectations the getInt(1) method does not give me the table's auto-incrimented id but an auto-incrimented value counting from 1 to the end of the resultset.

What do I get wrong?
I altered the code to use either com.mysql.jdbc as org.mariadb.jdbc connectors both updated to the latest version.

Or is it another option I need to set somewhere?

Anyways thanks for your help yet now.

```java
public void updateFZSetToUsed() {

    /*
     * Variablendeklaration
     * 
     */

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt1 = null, stmt2 = null;
    ResultSet rs = null, rs2 = null;

    String stmtstr1, stmtstr2;



    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception WPex) {
            System.out.println(WPex);
        }
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+configVars.getProperty("serverIP")+"/"+configVars.getProperty("db")+"?", configVars.getProperty("usr"), configVars.getProperty("pw"));


        stmt2 = conn.createStatement();


        stmt2.executeUpdate("UPDATE fz SET fz_used = 1 WHERE fz_id in (SELECT calls_fz FROM calls)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        rs2 = stmt2.getGeneratedKeys();

        while(rs2 != null && rs2.next()) {

            System.out.println(rs2.getInt(1));

        }





    } catch (SQLException singleStoreExc) {
        // handle any errors

        System.out.println("updateFZSetToUsed SQLException: " + singleStoreExc.getMessage());
        System.out.println("updateFZSetToUsed SQLState: " + singleStoreExc.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("updateFZSetToUsed VendorError: " + singleStoreExc.getErrorCode()); 

        return retString;
    } finally {

        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) 
            {
                System.out.println("rsclose fehler");
            }
            rs = null;
        }

        if (rs2 != null) {
            try {
                rs2.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) 
            {
                System.out.println("rs2close fehler");
            }
            rs2 = null;
        }



        if (stmt1 != null) {
            try {
                stmt1.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                System.out.println("stmt1cclose fehler");
            }

            stmt1 = null;
        }

        if (stmt2 != null) {
            try {
                stmt2.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                System.out.println("stmt2cclose fehler");
            }

            stmt2 = null;
        }

        if (stmt2 != null) {
            try {
                stmt2.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                System.out.println("stmt2cclose fehler");
            }

            stmt2 = null;
        }


        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                System.out.println("conn close() Error "+sqlEx);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many rows were changed, use a separate call to get "rows_affected".

If you need the `UPDATE` to run faster, either use a multi-table update or use `EXISTS`.  Either approach will probably avoid a full scan of `fx`.

`calls` needs `INDEX(calls_fz)`

I think `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` applies only to `INSERT` statements, not `UPDATE` statements; what do you think?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I needed a quick solution, so I build a work around for my problem. (2 different queries as far as I remember)

But actually it seems to be as you described: id values are only returned by INSERT statements. Maybe my memory tricked me on that detail, when I tried to recall mysqlI-XXX command specs from php.

Again, thanks for your input. I appreciate that.